# Hibernate not executing an UPDATE query

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to setup hibernate in a project, and as part of it, I'm trying to do a simple update query just to make sure that its able to work. Here's my code:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();

sess.beginTransaction();

sess.createSQLQuery("UPDATE fooTable SET bar='baz' ");
sess.getTransaction().commit();
sess.close();
```

When I run the code, everything executes without any error messages, and I see debug messages about getting a JDBC driver (using the config info I've provided), but the update query doesn't seem to be executed, as the table still shows the old info.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the query, but didn't execute it.

```
...
Query qry = sess.createSQLQuery("UPDATE fooTable SET bar='baz' ");
int updatedRows = qry.executeUpdate();
...
```

Comment: Use should check to result of the update, i.e. `int count = qry.executeUpdate();`